# Need some insight on how to create a delete function to remove a entry. I am intermediate at python programming. stuck here for a week

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x400+400+250")
window.title('Expenses Tracker')


class ExpensesTrack:

    row_list = []
    list_box = []
    dict1 = dict()


    def __init__(self,master):
        self.title1 = Label(window, padx=15, pady=8, text='Enter the item').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.title_price = Label(window, padx=8, pady=8, text='Enter the price').grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.entry1 = Entry(window, font='NEWTIMESROMAN')
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(window, font='NEWTIMESROMAN')
        self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.blank1 = Label(window).grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3)

        self.title3 = Label(window, text='Name of Item').grid(row=4, column=1 )
        self.title4 = Label(window, text='Price').grid(row=4, column=2)

        self.button1 = Button(window, text='Add', command= self.buttonclick).grid(row=1, column=4, padx=20)
        self.button2 = Button(window, text='Remove' )
        self.button2.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=15)



    def buttonclick(self):
        var = IntVar()

        def cmd():
            i = var.get()
            print(i)

        row = len(self.row_list) + 5
        name = Label(window, text=self.entry1.get())
        price = Label(window, text="$" + self.entry2.get())
        box = Checkbutton(window ,variable= var, command= cmd)

        name.grid(row= row, column=1)
        price.grid(row= row, column=2)
        box.grid(row=row, column=0)

        self.row_list.append(len(self.row_list) + 5)
        self.list_box.append(box)
        self.dict1[row] = price, name
        self.entry1.delete(0, END)
        self.entry2.delete(0, END)

e = ExpensesTrack(window)

window.mainloop()
```

''' I make a list of box when every time , I add check button.  I want to use destroy function iterate from the list_box. but I don't know how to check value of var , it is 1 or 0 for respective check button and later, I would add name and price label with it. Can any one tell a way that how to get var value from the box from list_box or any other way.

```
e = ExpensesTrack(window)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail or more specifically whats your problem is, what you want to achive. Please do attach the error your getting.

Comment: @FaraazKurawle, so I have `self.id_var.append(id(i))` , using id to located down the which var has value 1 and I have updated that to list. But, when iterate through it and use   `for i in self.list_box: i.destory()`                                                                                          it is show me this error **AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'destory'**

Comment: Based on your comment, you are calling `destory()` instead of `destroy()`.

Comment: @Blue_dayle , You want delete a specific widget type here checkbox(means all checkboxes), the only one widget(single checkbox) or all widget in the list.

Answer (score 1):

to remove items you shoud nav by var

```
list_var = []
# self.button2 = Button(window, text='Remove', command=self.remove )
def remove(self):
        for i, var in enumerate(self.list_var):
            if var.get() == 1:
                self.list_box[i].destroy()
                self.dict1[i][0].destroy()
                self.dict1[i][1].destroy()

def buttonclick(self):
    var = IntVar()
    row = len(self.row_list) + 5
    name = Label(window, text=self.entry1.get())
    price = Label(window, text="$" + self.entry2.get())
    box = Checkbutton(window ,variable= var)

    name.grid(row= row, column=1)
    price.grid(row= row, column=2)
    box.grid(row=row, column=0)
    
    self.dict1[len(self.row_list)] = price, name
    self.row_list.append(len(self.row_list) + 5)
    self.list_box.append(box)
    self.list_var.append(var)
    self.entry1.delete(0, END)
    self.entry2.delete(0, END)
```